# Beautiful Soup is not getting the entire table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to make a program that get the stock symbol from a list on Yahoo Finance. I have tried
changing html5lib to lxml and html.parser. Neither of those worked for me.
The website is: https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/f491bcb6-de80-4813-b50e-d6dc8e2f5623?dependentField=sector&dependentValues=Consumer%20Cyclical

There are supposed to be 25 results but if you see by running it we only get about half. (13)

Anyone got any solutions?

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36', 'Accept'          : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
 'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'DNT'             : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header 'Connection'      : 'close'
}

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/f491bcb6-de80-4813-b50e-d6dc8e2f5623?dependentField=sector&dependentValues=Consumer%20Cyclical'
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, timeout=5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

results = soup.find(id="screener-results")

stock_ = results.find_all("tr", class_="simpTblRow Bgc($hoverBgColor):h BdB Bdbc($seperatorColor) Bdbc($tableBorderBlue):h H(32px) Bgc($lv2BgColor)")

x = 0
for stock_ in stock_:
  x = x + 1
  stock_symbol = stock_.find('a', class_='Fw(600) C($linkColor)')

  print(str(stock_symbol.text.strip()) + '\n' + str(x))
```

Comment: only about half of the have a background of `Bgc($lv2BgColor)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy fix for this. The table is using alternating colors for each row so one row has the color `Bgc($lv2BgColor)` and the next one `Bgc($lv1BgColor)`. As you only get those with `Bgc($lv2BgColor)` you only get half of the results.
Here a screenshot [image: screenshot of relevant section of HTML page] of the relevant HTML of the webpage.

In your case there is actually no need to be so precise with the class, just use `class_="simpTblRow"` and you should get all results.

By the way: There also is a [Yahoo Finance API](https://www.yahoofinanceapi.com/) which is free for up to 100 requests per day so you might be able to use that instead of web scraping the from their web page.

Comment: Thank you! I want to scrape their page just because I'm learning how to still, but thanks for the suggestion :)